# sinatra will not load config data when started via systemd

Tags: ruby, sinatra, bundle, systemd

i have a sinatra app. when loaded locally via bundler, everything is fine. when i load the app via systemd the app got started, but the config file seems to be not loading. It says that in the logs that its loaded but the values are not available inside the app

The unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=PNL: Puppet Node Lister
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bundle exec ruby puppetdb_node_lister.rb
KillMode=process
Environment=RACK_ENV="production"
Restart=always
User=pnl
Group=pnl
WorkingDirectory=/opt/puppetdb_node_lister

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

my sinatra app:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/config_file'
require 'json'
require 'rest-client'
require 'date'
require 'time'
require 'active_support/time_with_zone'
require 'tilt/erb'

### local methods
require_relative 'lib/methods.rb'

config_file 'config.yaml'

### request area
get '/' do
 "#{settings.methods(false).inspect} <br/><br/> #{$:} <br/><br/> #{File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))}"

end
```

my yaml:

```
development:
  username: 'test'
  password: 'test'
  puppetdb: 'puppet.example.com'
  puppetsrv: 'puppet.example.com'
production:
  username: 'superadmin'
  password: 'somes3cret'
  puppetdb: 'puppet.example.com'
  puppetsrv: 'puppet.example.com'
```

local bundle output of /

```
[:app_file=, :app_file, :app_file?, :logging=, :logging, :logging?, :method_override=, :method_override, :method_override?, :run=, :run, :run?, :session_secret=, :session_secret, :session_secret?, :register, :environments=, :environments, :environments?, :username=, :username, :username?, :password=, :password, :password?, :puppetdb=, :puppetdb, :puppetdb?, :puppetsrv=, :puppetsrv, :puppetsrv?, :traps=, :traps, :traps?, :running_server=, :running_server, :running_server?, :handler_name=, :handler_name, :handler_name?] 

["/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/sinatra-contrib-1.4.7/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/tilt-2.0.4/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-2.6.4/hide_lib_for_update", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/netrc-0.11.0/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/multi_json-1.12.1/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/mime-types-2.99.2/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/http-cookie-1.0.2/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/domain_name-0.5.20160310/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/unf-0.1.4/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.2/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.2/lib", "/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.8/lib/gems/bundler-1.7.8/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/backports-3.6.8/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/thread_safe-0.3.5/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/minitest-5.9.0/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/json-1.8.3/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/json-1.8.3/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib", "/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.8/lib", "/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby", "/usr/local/lib64/ruby/site_ruby", "/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/usr/share/rubygems", "/usr/share/ruby", "/usr/lib64/ruby/"] 

/opt/puppetdb_node_lister
```

systemd output of /

```
[:app_file=, :app_file, :app_file?, :logging=, :logging, :logging?, :method_override=, :method_override, :method_override?, :run=, :run, :run?, :session_secret=, :session_secret, :session_secret?, :register, :environments=, :environments, :environments?, :traps=, :traps, :traps?, :running_server=, :running_server, :running_server?, :handler_name=, :handler_name, :handler_name?] 

["/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/sinatra-contrib-1.4.7/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/tilt-2.0.4/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/rubygems-update-2.6.4/hide_lib_for_update", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/netrc-0.11.0/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/multi_json-1.12.1/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/mime-types-2.99.2/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/http-cookie-1.0.2/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/domain_name-0.5.20160310/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/unf-0.1.4/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.2/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.2/lib", "/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.8/lib/gems/bundler-1.7.8/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/backports-3.6.8/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/thread_safe-0.3.5/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/minitest-5.9.0/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/json-1.8.3/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/json-1.8.3/lib", "/opt/puppetdb_node_lister/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib", "/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.8/lib", "/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby", "/usr/local/lib64/ruby/site_ruby", "/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/usr/share/rubygems", "/usr/share/ruby", "/usr/lib64/ruby/"] 

/opt/puppetdb_node_lister
```

one can see, that if loaded via systemd the values in settings (which would come from the yaml) are missing.

can anybody help me with that? am i doing this right, or is there i'm missing something?

Comment: tried to install all the gems system wide and start the service directly (without bundler) : same outcome. started on the cli all is fine, started via systemd it cannot load the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after all it was

```
Environment=RACK_ENV="production"
```

which should be more like

```
Environment=RACK_ENV=production
```

after this change, everything worked as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Your systemd configuration looks good to me. You set both the environment variables and the WorkingDirectory correctly.

Replace your app that with something that just dumps out the environment and the current directory. Run this test app through bundler, and also via systemd.

You should find there's still some difference between the environment that is being set up by systemd and your alternate method.   Resolve the differences. :)